# jQuery: Convert TextArea content to html string and vice versa

Tags: jquery, html, string

what I'm trying to do is converting a TextArea content into a valid html code. Suppose you type inside the TextArea and then you press a button that shows the typed text inside a element. If you typed something like inside the TextArea:

> Hi folks!
>   Do you like jQuery?
>   I do!

The resulting string you have to put inside the '' element is:

```
Hi folks!<br>Do you like jQuery?<br>I do!
```

That's because the newline inside the TextArea must be converted to the `<br>` tag!

The same thing should happend if you want to take the html of the  element and put it inside the TextArea input field, for example:

```
Hi folks!<br>Do you like jQuery?<br>I do!
```

should be converted to:

> Hi folks!
>   Do you like jQuery?
>   I do!

So, is there a way to convert a string to html-string (and vice versa) or should I write a function by myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can mark inline code with backticks `\``

Answer (score 29):

With the appropriate styling on the element, you shouldn't need to convert anything.  Using the CSS *white-space* property with a value set to *pre*, any white-space in the element should appear exactly as it does in the textarea:

```
#myElement { white-space: pre; }
```

Example:  **http://jsfiddle.net/TkpSu/**

Comment: thanks. Though it's a simple solution. but I had to waste much times for this solution.

Comment: Minor detail: In most cases `#myElement { white-space: pre-wrap; }` is probably a better fit to avoid overflowing content if users submit long texts without newlines.

Answer (score 13):

Well, it's not very difficult:

```
$('#element').html($('textarea').html().replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
```

Comment: Well, I was wondering if a jQuery conversion function had already been written, replacing tags by "hand" was obvious :)

Comment: That answers one part of it, but moving the text from the #element to the textarea with nothing but new lines is I think what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I had to use val() instead of html(), like so:
$('#_b').html($('#_a').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));

Comment: `It's not very difficult` - You're under the assumption that OP has mastered 100% of Javascript and jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking into a markdown editor.  Stack overflow uses a modified version of this one: http://wmd-editor.com/

Comment: fyi link's broken