# Formatting email text from jsp in HTML format using spring

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

i am implementing email service using spring, where users can enter the email subject and the Email body from the form and can send an email. Here i was able to send the email successfully..but I need to translate the line breaks/tabs entered by the user in the email body form and need to translate to the same in actual email that will be sent...as right now it don't translate the linebreaks and send all the text entered by the user in a single line..Need help in formatting this..

img link is one of the usecase with linebreaks in my email....
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHgZ7.jpg

below is my code...

```
    <div class="email-sm-textDiv">
        <textarea name="emailBodyTxtArea" id="emailBodyTxtArea"
            placeholder="Email Body"></textarea>
   </div>
```

ajax call:

```
submitHandler:function(form){
        var jsonObj = getData();        
        if(confirm("You are about to send Email Communication, Are you sure..?")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  $("#applicationUrl").val() +"/web/utilities/sendEmailMessage",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache:false,
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },
            data:JSON.stringify(jsonObj),  
       });
    }
        return false;
    }
function getData(){
            var object ={
                    emailSubject : $("#emailSubTxtArea").val(),
                    emailMsg : $("#emailBodyTxtArea").val()

            };
            return object;


        }
```

spring code:

```
    private boolean executeSendingEmail(String[] emailAddrs, String emailSubject, String emailMsg) throws MessagingException,MailException, Exception {
        MimeMessage message = null;
            try{
            message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
             MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
             helper.setFrom(emailFrom);
             helper.setTo(emailAddrs);
             helper.setSubject(emailSubject);
             helper.setText(emailMsg, true);
             mailSender.send(message);
             return true;
            }
            catch(MessagingException mesx){
                mesx.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            catch(MailException mx){
                mx.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
    }

}
```

I was able to send email successfully..But it is not in the format entered by the user in the form..below is my o/p email..

output:

```
HI Team, this is Test mail sending form Admin Application.... Sending this email for testing purpose... Ignore this mail.. regards, Admin.
```

So need help in formatting the email Msg entered by the user - which should be the same as entered by user..
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to send an email with an HTML body, or could it be just plain text? If just plain text is fine, then change `helper.setText(emailMsg, true);` to `helper.setText(emailMsg);`. Otherwise, you can search for "stackoverflow convert textarea value to html" and find answers.

Comment: Hi John, I need to send it in HTML body/style...will explore on that..can u help me with that, if you can..?

Comment: Since you need to send HTML, I think you have to do something like what @Mudassar suggests or put the text inside a `<pre>` element. If you google "stackoverflow convert textarea value to html" you will find other suggestions. Here's [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3804104/859640) with some possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text entered from a `<textarea>` will  have line breaks (\n) and HTML will interpret them as whitespace. Hence on the controller side, you need to do this:

```
String message = input.replace("\n", "<br />\n");
```

Or

```
message = input.replace("\n", "<br>");
```

Comment: Thanks Mudassar..the one which you said, helped me and i am getting the same format entered by the user.. cheers..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the TextArea to the Rich Text Editor called `CKEditor` and configure its editor with full page mode to make the html inside it as a full HTML Document via `fullPage = true;`

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('emailBodyTxtArea', {
            fullPage: true,
            toolbar : [
                { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike' ] },
                { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList' ] }
    });
</script>
```

---

**Another tricky solution:**

Instead of TextArea, use an Iframe:

```html
<iframe id="myIframe" srcdoc="<html><body contenteditable='true'></body></html>"></iframe>
```

Using JavaScript, you can get the content inside the iframe using the following code:

```js
var msg = document.getElementById("myIframe").contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Finally, try to style the iframe to make it look like the TextArea.